# Undefined index: HTTP_CONNECTION on Ubuntu18.04 Server/Apache 2.5

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Использую Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache 2.5 как платформу размещения своего сайта.

При заходенt сайт www.mysite.com через Browser я  должен вытянуть в index.php с помощью скрипта **$_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']** значение: close или keep-alive.

Но пишет мне в логах сервера Undefined index: HTTP_CONNECTION путь к логам *var/log/apache2/error.log.* Я не силен в сервере, почитал мануалки, понял что нужен толковый совет,кто сталкивался с настройками Apach2.5. Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Причем здесь сервер и заголовки с клиента? Уточните что и где вы пытаетесь получить и в каких логах видите это сообщение.

Comment: Изменил свою запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Клиент, которым вы обращаетесь к серверу, не передает HTTP-заголовок `Connection`, и в логах появляется ошибка:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_CONNECTION in...

Сравните два примера (по своим логам):

```
curl http://your-site.com/
```

и

```
curl --header "Connection: keep-alive" http://your-site.com/
```

**Apache 2.5**? Даже интересно где вы его взяли.Это вроде как ветка для разработчиков, не имеющая никакого релиза. Но могу конечно ошибаться.